# How to set key_type and value_type in DjangoCassandraModel Map field?

Tags: json, django, cassandra

In models.py:

```
import uuid
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from django_cassandra_engine.models import DjangoCassandraModel


class ExampleModel(DjangoCassandraModel):
    response = columns.Map(key_type=?, value_type=?)
```

I have a json response like this,

```
{
    "name": "MH Habib",
    "university": "X university" 
}
```

I want save this json into my model. I find out Map field is suitable for store json data. Now i have to set text type data in key_type and text type data in value_type. How can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have found an answer. When i set

```
response = columns.Map(key_type=columns.Text(), value_type=columns.Text())
```

Then run this command to sync the database

```
python manage.py sync_cassandra
```

Yeah ! This problem is solved.